# Performance boost from adding width and height attributes to image tags in html

Tags: html, django, image, performance, render

I maintain a Django forum where users can leave messages and photos for one another (or the entire public at large). Think of it like a counterpart of 9gag.

I benchmarked my website's performance via [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/). One of things it rated me lowly on is specificity of image dimensions. Specifically, it advises me to add image width and height within all `<img>` tags, so that browsers have an easier time rendering the page, minimizing repainting.

All uploaded images are dynamically re-sized and saved in the DB, maintaining their aspect ratio. The only way for me to include their heights and widths in their `<img>` tags on the template is if I saved their width or height in the DB as well. OR, if I read their width and height when serving them for viewing.

Either way, it's going to take some computing power on my part. It seems the trade-off here is between the server's computing time, versus the users' browsers. I.e. server-end or client-end. I do want to optimize the experience for my users, and my server resources are decent.

A new image gets uploaded on my website's public area every few seconds. You can say it's pretty much a staple of the website. Does anyone have experience of a big performance boost from including image width and heights in their template? I'd love to hear some advice on it, so I can go ahead with it (or dump the idea).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the precise layout of your site, then you could resize the image on user-upload and specify your dimensions using css.

If your site is responsive and the images scale according to device dimensions, then I wouldn't worry too much with this optimisation suggestion. [Twitter](https://twitter.com/) scores an F (0) for this on [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/), and has a D and B grade respectively but still has a faster load time than most sites.

**An afterthought as suggested by Hassan:**

My suggestion is that you focus on the internals of Django (eg. caching templates, using memcache, etc.) and then optimise delivery of static content (eg. compression in Nginx, say) and configure your web server's caching policies. This is where you'll notice a large performance gain. Lastly, if you have tons of page views, you may want to consider deploying [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/) or [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) in front of your web server.

Comment: Yep, it's the latter case. Thanks for the insights Keenan.

Comment: @HassanBaig, it's a pleasure. I recently went through the same process of performance grading vs load times. My suggestion is that you focus on the internals of Django (eg. caching templates, using memcache) and then optimise delivery of static content (eg compression in Nginx, say) and configure your web server's caching policies. This is where you'll notice a large performance gain. Lastly, if you have tons of page views, you may want to consider deploying [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/) or [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) in front of your web server.

Comment: That's a very useful comment Keenan. You could even add it in the answer as an afterthought (but a very useful afterthought). I'm sure it's going to be helpful for people coming here later.